# Spring library to share commons

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In a context of several spring boot apps, sharing some components, is that considered as a bad practice to publish an artifact used in those apps?

I'm planning to reuse controllers and services abstracts and low level classes (for statistics requiring fast write access, so webservices are excluded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two contrary paradigms, both definitely make sense on their own, but in this case they front each other. Hardcore microservice evangelists would roughly claim that there should be [**no common dependencies at all**](https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/01/microservices-sharing-code) to reduce coupling between the different services / applications. That means although in case the services share many architectural patterns, you have a lot of "copy and paste" code. And exactly that would make the [**don't repeat yourself**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) faction angry, because it makes also sense thinking about why not sharing already implemented functionality.

So the correct answer is: "It depends." It will always be a tradeoff between following the one law by violating the other. You can just make an economical / cost-effective decision and figure out what is feasible for your infrastructure and what causes less technical debt.